# php script output from another terminal

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php (cli) script on one terminal. It is constantly echoing the mysql calls etc. Is there any way I can see that output from another terminal, so that I can monitor the progress of that script?

Thanks

Comment: hint: /usr/bin/screen on unix

Comment: This looks similar... http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session

Comment: "/usr/bin/screen" no such directory or file found. Can you please tell me what steps should I take? I am on ubuntu.

Comment: `apt-get install screen`.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. use a [terminal multiplexer](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) or
2. modify your PHP script to write all output to a log file, or
3. pipe `stdout` and/or `stderr` to a log file (ex: `php myscript.php > output.log`). If you use a log file, you can monitor it in real time with `tail -f output.log`.

Comment: Thanks. But the script is not logging the output to any log file. And I can't edit the file at the moment as the script is still running. thanks

Comment: You might try `conspy` (another `apt-get`) or sniff around in `/dev/tty` or `/dev/pts` . You don't have many clean options if you can't stop the script and re-run it.